# What is the relationship between a program's output, standard output, and its file descriptors?

Tags: stdout, stdin, file-descriptors, stderr

Let's assume that I am running `wget` which is downloading something. It's printing some text to my terminal and writes the downloaded data into a file.

From a terminology point of view, what is the difference between the downloaded file and the information appearing in the console? What does this depend on that we consider something as "standard output" instead of "output"?

Who/What decides if some output is accessible via `/proc/self/fd/1` or by other means (file in the filesystem, window of a GUI program, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is standard output (1), error output (2), and input (0). These are the standard file descriptors:

```
tweedleburg:~ $ cat &
[1] 13089

[1]+  Stopped                 cat
tweedleburg:~ $ cd /proc/$!
tweedleburg:/proc/13089 $ cd fd
tweedleburg:/proc/13089/fd $ ls
0  1  2
```

Now the programmer can open files and every file opening delivers a file descriptor (for more info http://linux.die.net/man/2/open). Now let's look at this:

```
tweedleburg:~ $ wget www.linuxintro.org
[...]
2014-01-25 20:43:30 (157 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [19928]
```

Here the wget programmer decided to open a file (in this case index.html) for writing. It got some number as file descriptor but surely not 0, 1 or 2. The data from the internet is written into this. wget's programmer also decided that the "saved" line would be written to the error output stream. I can understand this as wget has or may get a parameter that dumps all data to standard output stream. Then it must not be mixed with status information.

This is why there are two output streams, standard out for data and error out for error/status messages. I blog about this here: http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Stdout,_stderr_and_stdin.

Now to get error output redirected you use the 2> operator, for standard output you use the 1> or > operator:

```
tweedleburg:~ $ wget >/dev/null
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
tweedleburg:~ $ wget 2>/dev/null
tweedleburg:~ $
```

you see - in the second example the error messages are suppressed :)

Comment: So, because "It got some number as file descriptor but surely not 0, 1 or 2", is 0,1, and 2 strictly related to some kind of a shell? Is the redirection the shell's redirection?

Comment: no, every process gets 0 as input stream, 1 as standard output stream and 2 as error output stream. These numbers cannot be assigned to opened files any more.